# The send function loops after you send a message having "pedro". It works fine without .lower but when i add it back so does it start to loop

Tags: python, discord.py

There is this error where it loops if i have .lower(). It works fine without it but then doesnt reply to anything execpt "pedro"

```
import os
import discord

TOKEN = os.environ['PedroBotKey']

client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} (aka Pedro) has connected to Discord!')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if "pedro" in message.content.lower():
    emoji = discord.utils.get(client.emojis, name='SmolSmolPedromin')
    await message.channel.send(str(emoji))

client.run(TOKEN)
```

It loops  on `Message.channel.send`. I'm new to python and dont know it very well. Not sure why it loops.

Comment: You're receiving the message that you're sending to the channel. Since it contains `Pedro`, you're responding to that.

Comment: So you're getting in a loop talking to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The bot is responding to itself so you need to check if the user is a bot or not

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if "pedro" in message.content.lower() and not message.author.bot:
    emoji = discord.utils.get(client.emojis, name='SmolSmolPedromin')
    await message.channel.send(str(emoji))
```